# abort currently running job in Salesforce

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

Is there a way to abort currently running batch job in Salesforce? I tried to run the query below and all it did was remove all jobs from Scheduled Jobs section without stopping the one that is currently running in the background. Please help. I would like to do it without contacting Salesforce support

```
    List<CronTrigger> jobsToAbort = [select Id from CronTrigger where CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'];
for (CronTrigger job : jobsToAbort) { System.abortJob(job.Id); }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Went to SetUp --> Monitoring --> Apex Jobs. There was Abort option :)

Comment: The navigation may have changed since this answer was written, but the page still exists here: `Setup -> Monitoring -> Jobs -> Scheduled Jobs`

Comment: New path is : Setup > Jobs > Apex Jobs or  Setup > Jobs > Scheduled Jobs

Answer (score 25):

Please run a SOQL query on AsyncApexJob with Status filter. **CronTrigger** is used to retrive Scheduled jobs wherein **AsyncApexJob** returns Apex Jobs (Running, Aborted, Pending, Completed etc.)

**SOLUTION:**

Use Below Code:-

```
for ( AsyncApexJob aJob : [ Select id ,Status, ApexClass.Name 
                              from AsyncApexJob where Status!='Aborted' 
                               and Status!='Completed' ] ){

      System.AbortJob(aJob.Id);

}
```

Comment: Very useful for killing a job running amok.  Thx.

Comment: This worked great for me, I could kill some jobs by Apex class name. Thanks.

Comment: And what if the count returned is more then 150, is there any way to abort the list of jobs in one go preventing 150 DML exception

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are in Lightning the Setup path has changed from the above:

```
Environments > Jobs > Apex Jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to abort the "currently running job" from within the batch itself due to an error condition that would prevent any of the following operations to succeed.  See example below:

```
global override void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
  try {
    /** do stuff **/
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    // the finish method isn't called when we abort, so I forced it to be
    finish(BC); 
    // Get current jobId from batch context to pass to the abort method
    System.abortJob(BC.getJobId());
    // Prevent rest of code in execute method from firing by exiting with return statement
    return;
  } 
}
```